# Programming with dplyr: Renaming a column with variable using glue syntax

Tags: r, dplyr, rename, rlang, tidyselect

I've read through [Programming with dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) and understand that `rename()` and `select()` use tidy selection. I'm trying to combine this with the glue syntax to create a custom function using the new double curly syntax (rlang v0.4.0), however I'm getting extra quotation marks:

```
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

sel_var = "homeworld"

# Attempt at using (newer) double curly syntax:
starwars %>% 
  select("{{sel_var}}_old" := {{ sel_var }})
#> # A tibble: 87 x 1
#>    `"homeworld"_old`
#>    <chr>            
#>  1 Tatooine               
#> # ... with 77 more rows

# Working, but uglier (and older) bang bang syntax:
starwars %>% 
  select(!!sym(paste0(sel_var, "_old")) := {{ sel_var }})
#> # A tibble: 87 x 1
#>    homeworld_old
#>    <chr>        
#>  1 Tatooine          
#> # ... with 77 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

How can I avoid the extra quotations marks in `` `"homeworld"_old` `` using the double curly `{{ }}` and glue `:=` syntax? This is shown to work for `summarise("mean_{{expr}}" := mean({{ expr }}), ...)` in a function [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#one-or-more-user-supplied-expressions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `{{` operator inside the glue mechanism works at the level of expressions, not strings. When an expression contains a string, the quotes (`"`) are also a part of that same expression, which is why you see them in the output. If you convert your string to a variable name, everything should work as expected:

```
sel_var <- as.name("homeworld")

starwars %>% 
  select("{{sel_var}}_old" := {{ sel_var }})
# # A tibble: 87 x 1
#    homeworld_old
#    <chr>        
#  1 Tatooine     
#  2 Tatooine     
# ...
```

**NOTE** that the `summarise("mean_{{expr}}" := mean({{ expr }}), ...)` example you linked has the same property. For example, here's one of the functions defined in that vignette:

```
my_summarise5 <- function(data, mean_var, sd_var) {
  data %>% 
    summarise(
      "mean_{{mean_var}}" := mean({{ mean_var }}), 
      "sd_{{sd_var}}" := mean({{ sd_var }})
    )
}
```

Everything works as expected when you pass variable names to the function:

```
my_summarise5( mtcars, mpg, mpg )
#   mean_mpg   sd_mpg
# 1 20.09062 20.09062
```

However, passing strings will include `"` in the output, as in your case:

```
my_summarise5( mtcars, "mpg", "mpg" )
#   mean_"mpg" sd_"mpg"
# 1         NA       NA
# Warning messages:
# 1: In mean.default(~"mpg") :
#   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
# 2: In mean.default(~"mpg") :
#   argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Comment: Ah that makes a lot more sense now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The value inside `{{}}` should be unquoted to be evaluated so create the column name before using them.

Here are two ways :

1. Using `curly-curly` (`{{}}`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

sel_var = 'homeworld'
new_col <- paste0(sel_var, '_old')

starwars %>% 
  select({{ sel_var }}) %>% 
  rename({{new_col}} := {{ sel_var }})

# A tibble: 87 x 1
#   homeworld_old
#   <chr>        
# 1 Tatooine     
# 2 Tatooine     
# 3 Naboo        
# 4 Tatooine     
# 5 Alderaan     
# 6 Tatooine     
# 7 Tatooine     
# 8 Tatooine     
# 9 Tatooine     
#10 Stewjon      
# … with 77 more rows
```

2. Using bang-bang (`!!`) will return the same output.

```
starwars %>% 
  select({{ sel_var }}) %>% 
  rename(!!new_col := {{ sel_var }})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm trying to avoid `paste0` and use the glue syntax. In the other dplyr examples, they show `data %>% summarise("mean_{{expr}}" := mean({{ expr }}),...` as a standard way of using the two together. I'll update my question to make it clearer

Comment: @Alwin in the link that you shared they have used glue syntax when the variable is passed as unquoted and not as string. Let's take `my_summarise4` function for example from that page. `my_summarise4(mtcars, cyl)` works but `my_summarise4(mtcars, "cyl")` does not. `sel_var` that you have is a string value.

Comment: I would steer away from the term "(un)quoted", because there's an unfortunate ambiguity between the string quotes `"` and the expression quoting via `quote()`. When somebody says "x must be (un)quoted", it's not always clear if the are referring to `"x"` or `quote(x)`.